# Create or choose a record when using accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I have the following:

`app/models/order.rb`

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client    
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :client
end
```

`app/models/client.rb`

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :orders
end
```

When an **Order** is being saved I'd like to

- Check if there an existing **Client** with an email specified
- If exists, choose it for the **Order**
- If not, create a **Client** with the provided attribute and link it to my **Order**

Should I use **before_save** for the **Client** or what's the best way of achieving it?

Thanks fellows!

## ======== SOLVED! ========

Comment: So, you are adding clients to orders and not orders to clients?  If that's the case, what does this order form look like?

Comment: I create a client in case he hasn't ordered anything before and I don't have his info. I use the Client model only for my internal statistics to let managers know who are they dealing with. The form consists of Client information plus product id and other stuff.

Comment: Glad to see you got it working the way you want! :) Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to *Fishz* I played around and found the following solution:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

    before_validation :check_client_existance

    def check_client_existance
       if client = Client.find_by_email(self.client.email)
          self.client = client
       end 
    end

end
```

Thanks =)

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `before_create` for the Order, method could look like:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :determine_client
  ...
  def determine_client
    if Client.exists?(:email => self.email_variable)
      self.client_id = Client.find_by_email(self.email_variable)
    else
      cur_client = Client.create!({ :email => self.email_variable })
      self.client_id = cur_client.id
    end
  end
end
```

This is basic but you could build from there. Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, the **before_create** is called after Rails saves the client. =(